# router.navigate not working properly with guards

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have 2 routes in my app:

1. '/auth', with the guard IsNotLoggedIn.
2. '/main', with the guard IsLoggedIn.

inside '/auth' i have 2 child routes:
 1. 'landing' - a page that has a button that leads to the login page.
 2. 'login' - a simple login page

inside '/main' i have 1 child route:
 1. 'home' - my home page.

In my root route '/' I redirect to '/auth', there the **IsNotLoggedIn** guard checks if the user is not logged in

- if he is not, he is redirected to '/auth/landing'.
- If the user is logged in I redirect him to '/main'

In my **IsLoggedIn** guard I check if the user is logged in

- If the user is logged in I redirect him to '/main'
- if he is not, he is redirected to '/' (then he is redirected to '/auth').

**My problem starts after login**

After the user login I call route.navigate(['/']). The result should be that the user is finally redirected to '/main/home' but for some reason he is redirected to '/auth/landing'.
**When I look at the log I see that non of my guards were called.**
When I refresh the page the user is redirected to '/main/home' as it should have in the first place.

Please help me with this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Your actual code, brief and minimalistic would be much better

Comment: What version are you using and why did you include both Angular and AngularJS tags?

Comment: Please provide some codes.